# How to remove KDE icons from Ubuntu 20.04 after uninstalling Latte Dock

Tags: kde, icons, uninstall, latte-dock

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed. I got these KDE icons after installing "Latte Dock" on Ubuntu. But after removing Latte Dock:, I still have these KDE icons. I have also tried
`sudo apt remove kde-full`, `sudo apt autoremove` and `sudo apt remove –purge kubuntu-desktop kde-standard language-pack-kde-en` but nothing is happening for these KDE icons to be removed.

Clicking here you can see the KDE icons I want to remove.

[image: Clicking here you can see the KDE icons I want to remove]

Comment: I don't think they are icons, but they are applications.  Looks like `kdeconnect` and `kwalletmanager` - I'd try to remove those. Don't forget to run `sudo apt update` first. You can also take a look at your apt logs/history to see exactly which packages were installed

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20.4.

Comment: @David I know. I just forget to add "0" after decimal point and before "4"

Answer (score 2):

Check for said items within /usr/share/applications/

To verify, review the Name= field inside, or search for the terms you want to remove.

```
$ cd /usr/share/applications/
$ grep -lR -e "KDE Connect" -e "KDE System Settings" -e "KWallet"
```

With results, move them into a directory where the system wont see them.

```
$ mkdir hidden_items
$ mv kde-description.desktop ./hidden_items
$ cd hidden_items
$ ls
```

You might need sudo privileges.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it works removing this packages

```
sudo apt remove kded5 kdeconnect kwalletmanager
sudo apt autoremove
```